# Как не прописывать одни и те же методы во всех классах, которые отличаются одной строкой?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеются 2 метода StatsUpdate() и ActionAdd(). Они используются в 3х классах и дальше будут использоваться примерно в 8 классах. Логика у них одинковая во всех классах. За исключение 1 строки

```
MyClass.Instanse.Actions = actions;
```

Различия только в том, в какой класс отдаются данные.

Хочется прописать его один раз, а не в каждом классе. Как сделать так, чтобы метод понимал куда отдавать данные?
Есть вариант передавать в метод имя класса из которого он вызывается, и после через if else выбирать куда посылать данные. Но я думаю есть более изощренный способ это сделать

UPDATE:
Код

```
public StatsModelBase StatsUpdate(StatsModelBase _stats, string _class, string _status)
        {
            var stats = _stats;
            _stats = new StatsModelBase()
            {
                Status = _status ?? stats.Status,
            };

            if (_class == "Class1")
                Class1ViewModel.Instanse.Stats = _stats;
            else if (_class == "Class2")
                Class2ViewModel.Instanse.Stats = _stats;
            else if (_class == "Class3")
                Class3ViewModel.Instanse.Stats = _stats;

            return _stats;
        }
```

В StatsUpdate в параметр class передаю this.GetType().Name при его вызове. Я думал есть более правильный способ это сделать, но он оказался слишком большим для такой задачи

Comment: Слышали про Generic классы. Вдруг ваш случай?

Comment: aepot слышал и спасибо что напомнили про него, они могут помочь, но не с этой проблемой)

Comment: В таком случае лично мне ваш вопрос не понятен, так как его можно решить разными способами. Один из которых вам не подходит, неизвестно, почему.

Answer (score 1):

Отнаследуйтесь от базового класса.

Допустим у вас есть два класса:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void StatsUpdate()
    {
        // общие действия во всех классах
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
        
        // различающаяся одна строчка
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}


public class Bar
{
    public void StatsUpdate()
    {
        // общие действия во всех классах
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome");

        // различающаяся одна строчка
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```

Сделайте базовый:

```
public class FooBarBase
{
    protected void CommonLogic()
    {
        // общие действия во всех классах
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
    }
}
```

и наследников:

```
public class Foo : FooBarBase
{
    public void StatsUpdate()
    {
        CommonLogic();

        // различающаяся одна строчка
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}


public class Bar : FooBarBase
{
    public void StatsUpdate()
    {
        CommonLogic();

        // различающаяся одна строчка
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```

Эффект - тот же самый:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();

foo.StatsUpdate();
bar.StatsUpdate();
```

Ну а дальше по вкусу... можно передавать переменные в базовый метод, чтобы включать или выключать в нём логику, использовать проверки на тип наследника, например:

```
protected void CommonLogic()
{
    if(this.GetType() == typeof(Bar))
        Console.WriteLine("Foo logic");
        
    // общие действия во всех классах
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
}
```

ну и так далее.

А вообще, сдаётся мне, что если у вас 8 классов, то там скорее всего тоже копипасты много и всё отличается незначительно, можно обобщить.

Comment: A K, выглядит красиво и понятно, но с другой стороны слишком много кода